# Best way to log an override method

Tags: c#

Taking the example of [DotNetPerls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/override)

```
class A
{
    public virtual void Y()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A.Y");
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public override void Y()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B.Y");
    }
}
```

How can I safely call a method in the `Y` method, for example, to log some action, without the need to edit every single implementation?

I know the `virtual` makes the method overridable and that the original method is never called unless you use the `base` caller, I also investigated a bit about [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net) but does not seem to help here...

Just trying to get my head around in order log some calls without the need to edit each and ever implementation :(

Comment: You could use `Castle.DynamicProxy` for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split the public interface and the inheritor's obligations into two methods:

```
class A
{
    public void Y()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Y about to happen");
        InnerY();
        Console.WriteLine("Y happened");
    }
    protected virtual void InnerY()
    {
    }
}

class B : A
{
    protected override void InnerY()
    {
        //No need to log - already done
    }
}
```

Comment: still need to edit every existing implementation, as I need to change the call from `Y` to `innerY` :(

Comment: Ah - I understood the editing concern to be "If I change the logging requirements later, I'll have to edit everywhere". Yes, you need to edit each implementation - once.

Comment: @balexandre - you mean "change the override from `Y` to `innerY`". The *call* to `Y` can stay the same. So you "just" need to change the inheriting classes.

Comment: In your suggested solution, the log will not contain the specific type that it's Y was called. I'll bet one of us misunderstood the question. I thought that the point was to log both the class name and the method name without having to hard-code them in every method...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I ended up using this method, the culprit is small and provides what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use StackTrace to get the information of the current (or calling) method along with the information of the object it resides on.

```
public class A
{
    public virtual string Y()
    {
        return Log.GetMethodName();
    }
}

public class B : A {
    public override string Y()
    {
        return Log.GetMethodName();
    }
}

public class Log
{
    public static string GetMethodName()
    {
    var st = new StackTrace();
    var sf = st.GetFrame(1);
    var method = sf.GetMethod();
        return method.DeclaringType.Name +"."+ method.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you could follow C# name conventions, that'd be great.

Comment: @Bauss edited. it's just an example I've written in a harry, but you have a point there - If one of my developers would write code like this I would make him fix that.